# Declaring a date as being the last month day of another date

Tags: sql-server, date, declare, sapb1

I'm trying to write a financial report on our SAP B1 system using SQL Server Studio.

In my report I want the information to be calculated on a month to month basis. In my report I have @start date as @Startofcurrentfinancialyear, and my end as DD+30 (because there are 31 days in the month) However I am wanting to have mm+1 and dd-1 to bring me to the last day in the month.

I plan on changing the report for each month to give me the following.
MM+1 (for month 2) and MM+2 - DD 1 to give me the date range for month 2 etc.

Currently, I can make this go based on the following: MM+0, DD+30, then going ahead doing DD+60 etc and calculating for each month how many days they are, but this will give me problems with leap years.

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(MM,-0,@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear)
DECLARE @End DATETIME = DATEADD(DD,+30,@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear)
```

I expect to be able to define a month for each section and give the last day of the defined month based on the parameters given above.

Comment: Why not use `EOMONTH` instead? Not every month is 30 days, so just adding 30 seems like a bad idea. Also what is `DATEADD(MM,-0,@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear)` trying to achieve? That'll just return `@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear` as *value* ± 0 = *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the end of month, then in all supported versions of SQL Server, you can do:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -0, @StartOfCurrentFinancialYear);
DECLARE @End DATETIME = EOMONTH(@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear);
```

If you are using an unsupported version, you can do date arithmetic:

```
DECLARE @End DATETIME = DATEADD(day, -1,
                                DATEADD(month, 1,
                                        DATEADD(day,
                                                1 - DAY(@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear), 
                                                @StartOfCurrentFinancialYear
                                               ),
                                       )
                                 );
```

This does the following calculation:

- Innermost subquery `dateadd()` moves to the first day of the month.
- Middle subquery adds one month.
- Outer query subtracts one day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want start of the month and end of the month you can get it by using **`DateAdd`** function like :

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, (DAY(GETDATE()) * -1) + 1, GETDATE())
DECLARE @End DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY, DAY(GETDATE()) * -1, GETDATE()))
SELECT @Start, @End
```

you can replace GETDATE() with your date variable so after your replacement the code should be something like this :

DECLARE @StartOfCurrentFinancialYear AS DATE = '31/aug/2019'

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, (DAY(@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear) * -1) + 1, @StartOfCurrentFinancialYear)
DECLARE @End DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY, DAY(@StartOfCurrentFinancialYear) * -1, @StartOfCurrentFinancialYear))
SELECT @Start, @End
```